# Invalid value for 'envelopeEventStatusCode'

Tags: docusignapi

Suddenly Docusign Demo API began to return

> ```
> [errorCode] => INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER
> [message] => The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Invalid value for 'envelopeEventStatusCode' in envelope: 'Signed'
> ```

We have the same code in production and it's fine we only got this error on DEMO API, maybe it's  something about the DocuSign Fall ’14 Release ?

Comment: Can you show your full request?

Comment: did you find the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I was sending invalid status code

> "envelopeEventStatusCode" => "Signed"

Which do not exists, but in the past the api doesn't complain about it